# Prove that $\binom{2n}{n} > \prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Good afternoon everyone. I'm confused about this problem. At the book  *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen is written that the next proposition is true:

$$\binom{2n}{n} > \prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p}$$

But,

$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}{n!}$$

We can see that $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}{n!}$ is divisible by all primes such that $n < p < 2n$. That implies:

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)}{n!} = \frac{(\prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p})t}{n!}$$
with $\gcd(t, \prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p}) = 1$ This implies that prime numbers $p$ of the decomposition of $t$ are smaller than $n$. Thus, there is a integer $r$ such that:

$$n! = t*r \Rightarrow \frac{(\prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p})t}{n!}= \frac{(\prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p})t}{t*s} = \frac{(\prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p})}{s} \leq \prod_{p > n}^{p<2n}{p} $$

This is a contradiction of the proposition.

What is it wrong of my reasoning?

PD: $n$ is an integer.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This fact is written in a very good book of elementary number theory so I think I am wrong, not the authors of the book.

Comment: Tip: do not use symbols like $\exists$, $\implies$ or $/$. Use words. Humans communicate using words. You are reading an extraordinarily good book: learn not only the math from it but their beautiful style. Notice how they essentially do not use those signs.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thank you for your comment. I thought that "Mathematics Stack Exchange" site wanted the most formal language. Now I 'm going to edit this post to change this symbols.

Comment: No one wants «the most formal language».

Comment: it is obvious you wrote it : ${2n \choose n}$ is an integer divisible by all the primes $n < p < 2n$

Comment: Stupid, obvious uestion: is there a way to use Chebychev's Theorem or the methods of its proof?

Comment: Your assumption that $gcd(t, \prod_{p > n}^{p < 2n} p) = 1$ is false. In general, $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (2n)$ will be divisible by higher powers of a given prime $p$ with $n < p < 2n$. Thus $t$ will in general be divisible by some primes in the interval $(n, 2n)$.

Comment: @M If $p>n$, then the only number $\le2n$ that is divisible by $p$ is $p$ itself. - Nevertheless, $t$ must be divisible by $n!$ because $2n\choose n$ is ultimately an integer. That is, $ t=s\cdot n!$ instead of $n!=s\cdot t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof that $\binom{2n}{n}> \prod_{p>n}^{p<2n}{p}$ for $n\geq2$:

notice $\binom{2n}{n}$ is even since we can pair every subset with its complement. Also notice that every prime $n<p<2n$ divides $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ since it divides the numerator and not the denominator.

We conclude $2\prod_{p>n}^{p<2n}$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ and therefore $2\prod_{p>n}^{p<2n}\leq \binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: But this is true if $\binom{2n}{n}$ is an integer. Can you prove this?

Comment: It's the number of subsets of size $n$ of $\{1,2,3\dots 2n\}$, of course it is an integer.

Comment: Thank you, never before have I worked with binomial coefficients in number theory and for this reason I didn't know this fact.

Comment: @RubénBallester By definition (at least etymologically), $n\choose k$ is the **coefficient** of $x^k$ when expanding the **binomial** $(1+x)^n$. And that is also readily shown to be an integer

Answer (score 3):

This made me want to point out Legendre's Theorem, which states that the power of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\nu_{p}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{i}} \Bigg\rfloor.
\end{equation*}

Using this it is immediate to see that 
\begin{equation*}
\prod_{p > n, \, p \, \mathrm{prime}}^{p < 2n}p
\end{equation*}
divides $(2n)!$, but no prime $p$ with $n < p < 2n$ divides $n!$. Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}
\end{equation*}
is divisible by the above product as well.

Comment: Em! Isn't the general notation $v_{p}(n)$ rather than $v_{n}(p)$??

Comment: Yes, I realized that I switched the notation from what was stated on the wikipedia article. But honestly, as long as everything is clearly defined it doesn't matter what notation you use.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $t$ is a multiple of $n!$. You asserted, correctly, that the primes that divide $t$ are primes $\le n$. However, their multiplicities in the prime factorization of $t$ may not be the same as their multiplicities in the prime factorization of $n!$, so we cannot conclude that $t$ divides $n!$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But that implies that $t > n!$ if the proposition is true. How can you proof that fact? Thank you

Comment: That $t$ is a multiple of $n!$ is clear, for the binomial coefficient $\frac{(n+1)\cdots (2n)}{n!}$ is an integer, and the product $P$ of your "big" primes is relatively prime to $n!$. That gives $t\ge n!$. It takes only a little more to prove strict inequality.